# Problems with has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords

I'm trying to create a user model that uses `has_secure_password`, I've followed examples from the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password) and it still fails.

This is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :full_name, :password_digest
  has_secure_password
end
```

And I'm trying to create a user like so:

```
@user = User.new({
  username: params[:user][:username],
  password: params[:user][:password],
  password_confirmation: params[:user][:password_confirmation],
  email: params[:user][:email],
  full_name: params[:user][:full_name]
})

# I even tried with `@user.new(params[:user])`
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password, password_confirmation
```

I've tried searching for solutions on here and google, taken a look at "sample apps" and I appear to be doing the same as they are, except that I'm still getting the error.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `:password, :password_confirmation` to `attr_accessible`, that might be the problem.